# Variable loses its value PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have the code below where my variable `$layout` loses it's value and I have no idea why, the `layoutContent` is just a method that get the template of my website, then
`renderOnlyView` get the view supposed to render in that template

```
$layout = $this->layoutContent($layoutParams);
echo ($layout);
$view = $this->renderOnlyView($view, $params);
echo ($layout);
```

the whole method where the bug occurred

```
public function renderView(string $view, array $params = [], array $layoutParams = [])
{
    $layout = $this->layoutContent($layoutParams);
    echo ($layout);
    $view = $this->renderOnlyView($view, $params);
    echo ($layout);

    $layout = str_replace('{{ title }}', $layoutParams['title'] ?? 'No title', $layout);
    
    return str_replace('{{ body }}', $view, $layout);
}
```

and `renderOnlyView`

```
protected function renderOnlyView(string $view, array $params): ?string
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        $$key = $param;
    }
    ob_start();
    $viewFilePath = Application::$ROOT_DIR . "/views/$view.blade.php";
    if (file_exists($viewFilePath))
        include_once $viewFilePath;
    else
        echo "the view <b>$view</b> is not found";

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

`layoutContent` just in case

```
public function layoutContent(array $params = [])
{
    $layout = Application::$APP->controller->layout ?? 'main';
    ob_start();
    include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR . "/views/layout/$layout.layout.php";
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        $output = str_replace('{{ ' . $key . ' }}', $param, $output);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

more infos: PHP Version: 7.4.3, system ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What's happening in the `$viewFilePath` file? If it's doing something like `global $layout;` then you might have problems.

Comment: @kmoser I don't use global variables, $viewFIlePath has only the full path to my view file, I carried away your theory, and renamed my variable layout to template same still happening

Comment: PHP is not Java. `$this->layout` is a class property, `$layout` is a local variable. They aren't the same variable.

Comment: Excuse me asking but where is that `$this->layout`?

Comment: `Application::$APP->controller->layout` is a property of the controller class. All other references to `layout` that start with `$` are an (unrelated) local variable. I'm not saying that the issue but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U missed a point, this function get called two times, the first time when you rendering my view, the second time when you view throw an error and while catching it and trying to display the renderLayout get called again, causing the include_once to return null since it was already included

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys problem found, i missed a point, this function get called two times, the first time when I'm rendering my view, the second time when my view throw an error and while catching it and trying to display the `renderLayout` get called again, causing the include_once to return null since it was already included :D